# Executing a shell function embedded in a script read with cat

Tags: bash, function, shell, call, cat

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function foo(){
    param=$1
    echo "$param"
}


content="calling this one with param: $(foo 'this is test param1')"

echo "$content"
```

**result**: calling this one with param: this is test param1

**Notice that foo is called**

But, the following does not work when content moves to test.txt file i.e. test.txt has - calling this one with param: `$(foo 'this is test param1')`

```
fileName="test.txt"

content=$(cat "$fileName")



echo "$content"
```

**result**: calling with param: $(foo 'this is test param1')

**Notice that foo is not called**

Question: how to call foo for the second case

Comment: Why would you expect storing the contents of a file in a variable to run those contents as a script? It would be impossible to write secure shell scripts that dealt with file IO if reading from a file automatically ran that content as an executable.

Comment: `$(foo 'this is a test param1')`, by the way, **is inherently broken**: It tries to run the output of the `foo` function as a command itself. You surely don't want to do that, so your filename should just contain `foo 'this is a test param1'`, without the `$()`s surrounding.

Comment: Try running `content=$( $( foo 'this is a test param1' ) )`, and you'll see it fail the same way.

Answer (score 2):

#### Sample Implementation

```
## Setting up the input file
fileName=foo.txt
cat >"$fileName" <<'EOF'
foo 'this is test param1'
EOF

## Running the test
foo() {
  param=$1
  echo "$param"
}

content=$(source "$fileName")
echo "$content"
```

#### ...emits output:

```
this is test param1
```

---

#### Notes

- The input file here contains `foo 'this is test param1'`, not `$(foo 'this is test param1')`. Otherwise, you'd have two `$()`s nested, meaning that the outer one one would be executing the output of the inner one as a command (after [parsing it in a way very unlikely to be useful](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)).
- Reading a file is necessarily different from executing it. `foo=$(cat bar)` assigns the exact output of `cat bar` to `foo`; it doesn't actually run the contents of `bar` as if they were a script.
- To have a function available in a given shell, it either needs to be exported by a parent process (with `export -f`), or defined in either that same shell, or a shell of which the executing shell is a subshell (a "subshell" being a shell instance created by a `fork()` with no `exec()` following it).
- Using the `source` keyword runs a file's contents in the existing shell.
- Using `$()`, like `( )`, implicitly creates a subshell. Functions from the parent shell are available in this context, even if not exported, unless running an independent shell instance explicitly (by calling `bash`, `sh`, or similar).
- If you **really** wanted to use `cat`, you could run `content=$(eval "$(cat "$fileName")")` -- though this is worse in almost every way from `source`.

Comment: okay but the input file should contain `$(foo 'this is test param1')`. That's why we don't agree on my answer :)

Comment: I'm holding fast to the position that the given input file contents are poorly chosen, and the OP should correct them. I mean, yes, it's possible to use `eval` to generate a string that makes those contents kinda-sorta useful, but that's going through a bunch of hackery for something less flexible than doing the usual and conventional thing of treating the file's contents as a sourceable script (and writing them simply as `foo 'this is a test param1'`, without the extraneous `$()`s).

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
content=$(cat "$fileName")
```

just runs the `cat` command and stores the contents of the file in `$content`. It does not execute the script. If you want to execute the script:

```
content=$(bash "./$fileName")
```

Comment: ...ideally the script would be marked executable and have its own shebang line, so `content=$( "$(readlink -f "$fileName")" )` or similar would work. (`"./$fileName"` assumes that the file is in the current directory, and that may not always be true -- would behave badly with an already-qualified path).

Comment: btw, this doesn't make the `foo` function available as-written. Consider using `source` instead of starting a separate interpreter.

Comment: did not work: $ ./test.sh
./test.txt: line 1: foo: command not found
./test.txt: line 1: calling: command not found

Comment: @ChessSeven, that's exactly what `$(foo 'this is a test param1')` does, because of the `$()`s -- they tell the shell to run the **output** of the `foo` function as a command itself. If you want `content` to be `calling this one with param: this is a test param1`, take out the surrounding `$()`s.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a hack but does the job:

```
fileName="test.txt"

function foo(){
    param=$1
    echo "$param"
}
# export the function
export -f foo
# pipe result to bash with a temp variable (bash $fileName won't consider foo for some reason)
echo "z=$(cat $fileName); echo \"\$z\"" | bash
```

Comment: Why would you do all that work instead of, say, `source "$fileName"`, or (to isolate it in a subshell) `(source "$fileName")`? No need for exported functions that way,

Comment: ...and `echo \$z` is full of bugs because of the lack of quoting. Look at what happens if the source to your file contains, say, a literal asterisk. You have a similar bug with `cat $fileName` -- what if the filename contains a space?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: try it yourself, it does not work: `./test.txt: line 1: this: command not found`. I agree it should...

Comment: "try it yourself" -- exactly which value of "it"? `source "$fileName"` certainly works.

Comment: I mean I tried and it didn't work (using MSYS on windows). BTW quoting fixed thanks. I agree it should work in theory but the function certainly has something to do with it failing for me (no irony intended with the "try it yourself". Let me rephrase: test your solution in that particular case)

Comment: See my answer, which includes the exact code I used, including setting up the target filename. If you copy/paste that, do you get the same error you report above?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I trust you it works, but the contents of the input file is different from the OP question.

Comment: Sure, because the OP wrote it wrong in their question. There are no reasonable circumstances under which that code is correct; they should be encouraged to fix it, not given a hack that makes it work.

Comment: You're right. That was funny, though. So I'm going to delete my answer since it is not useful.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the argument to foo function.

```
function foo(){
    param=$1
    echo "$param"
}

fileName="test.txt"

content=$(foo "$(cat "$fileName")")

echo "$content"
```

Comment: foo function got pasted in single line, please correct that and run it. May be it provides the answer for your query.

Comment: FYI, the `function` keyword is a bashism -- it makes your code less portable than it would be without it, using standard POSIX sh function declaration syntax.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I generally BASH shell for scripting.

Comment: So do I, but I use POSIX syntax when the bash-only syntax gives me no advantage over the standard form. That way if I *do* need to write something to work in a POSIX shell, I don't have habits leading me the wrong way.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I will also consider this into my practice then, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Consider also, btw, making it `content=$(foo "$(cat "$fileName")")` if you don't want any of the expansions to be string-split into multiple arguments. (I'm not making any judgment on correctness of the answer as a whole there, but it's certainly more correct if it passes the output of `cat` to `foo` as a single argument than if it's one argument per word).